# How to configure ASP.NET session state on AMAZON RDS?

Tags: amazon-rds

I have website with front-end in asp.net and database is MySQL. I could store the session state in database in MySQL locally by using Visual Studio Website Configuration Tool. How could I do the same on Amazon RDS. If you think it has been answered before please do let me know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to setup sessionState with SQL Server mode on Amazon RDS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636919/how-to-setup-sessionstate-with-sql-server-mode-on-amazon-rds)

Comment: If you are using .net, you can use the SDK for .net that has helpers to handle session state. http://aws.amazon.com/pt/sdk-for-net/

Comment: @rcdmk thank for the link and as per your link, I think dynamodb is something which I need to look into, even though I was looking something familiar to Visual Studio website config tool.

Comment: Have you solved your issue? If so, please, add your solution as an answer to the question and mark it as solved. This way you can help other with the same problem.

Comment: @rcdmk I'm still working on that and will surely update once I'm done with.